# How to fix webview in center of the page

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my webview

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(visible: checkDownload, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: WebviewScaffold(
              url: weburl,
              withZoom: true,
              hidden: true,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('View ' + type),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                      onPressed: () {
                        getPermission('print');
                      }),
                ],
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I am implementing webview in my Flutter application which has to be center of the page. But the issue is my webview is locating top of the page and also I have tried giving center widget to locate the webview into center of page. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview in center of the page you can set as below,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View ' + type),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.print),
            onPressed: () {
              getPermission('print');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(visible: checkDownload, child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.5,
              child: WebviewScaffold(
                url: weburl,
                withZoom: true,
                hidden: true,
                bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your `Stack` widget is does not automatically wrap to the size of it's children. currently your stack is tiny an automatically aligned to the top left corner. so aligning it's children to the center wont make a difference.

a better solution would be:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
   child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(visible: checkDownload, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: WebviewScaffold(
              url: weburl,
              withZoom: true,
              hidden: true,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('View ' + type),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                      onPressed: () {
                        getPermission('print');
                      },
                   ),
                ],
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i tried with your above code but not worked